# Friends Can any one explain this code

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm new to android i want to design spalash screen , i cant understand this code

Comment: Yup, it starts a new activity in SPLASH_TIME_OUT milliseconds, and ends this one.  Its a splash screen implementation.  Ought to work fairly well, unless the user is constantly rotating his phone during it, in which case it would stay open too long.

Comment: You should be a little more specific as to what parts confuse you, then adjust the title to be less broad

Comment: Guys i want to know about this code work new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining code.

Comment: Please reformat this post as a question or it will probably be flagged for removal. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have Read CODE little more carefully........You could understood by your own..because there is comments defined there for understanding that code............**

Though,below there is description for the code ...

Its A Activity For Creating SPLASH SCREEN.............

IT uses Handler which runs after specified time Defined In.. `SPLASH_TIME_OUT`

There is

> 1000 = 1 Sec;

So if you have defined `3000` value to `SPLASH_TIME_OUT` , new `Activity` which is **MainActivity.class** will open after 3 seconds....

> `Intent` is used here to  start new Activity after specified time....with the help of `startActivity(intentobject);`
>
> and current activity (**`SplashScreen.this`**) will be closed because of `finish()` method...

Answer (score 1):

After the `SPLASH_TIME_OUT` time, the run method of the Handler is called, starting the MainActivity. In the mean time, the splash screen is shown.

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) !

By the way, a splash screen is an anti-pattern on android and shouldn't be used !
To know why, read this great article : [Splash Screens Are Evil, Don't Use Them!](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)

Answer (score 0):

**If your application is packaged in a jar file, you can use the "SplashScreen-Image" option in a manifest file to show a splash screen**. Place the image in the jar archive and specify the path in the option. The path should not have a leading slash.

> **The splash screen is displayed as an undecorated window containing an image**.  You can use GIF, JPEG, or PNG files for the image.
>   Animation is supported for the GIF format, while transparency is
>   supported both for GIF and PNG. The window is positioned at the center
>   of the screen. The position on multi-monitor systems is not specified.
>   It is platform and implementation dependent. The splash screen window
>   is closed automatically as soon as the first window is displayed by
>   Swing/AWT

Your code will show the splash screen till  SPLASH_TIME_OUT is called. which start the MainActivity after the splash screen .(consider your splash screen as a screen saver.)

> If the Java implementation provides the command-line interface and you
>   run your application by using the command line or a shortcut, use the
>   Java application launcher option to show a splash screen. The Oracle
>   reference implementation allows you to specify the splash screen image
>   location with the -splash: option.  For example:
>
> java -splash:filename.gif Test